# How do I give a workflow permissions without giving them to the user?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I have a realtime workflow that automatically creates a new instance of an entity (CustomLog) when a field on a different entity is changed (CustomIssue). I don't care about permissions on CustomIssue, but I would like to restrict permissions on CustomLog to read-only for all users. However, this means that the workflow can't execute correctly when a CustomIssue is changed.

I've tried creating a new user with unlimited CustomLog permissions, setting them as the workflow's owner and then setting the workflow to run under the owner's name. But I still get the error `Principal user is missing prvCreatenew_customlog privilege`. Is there a way to let the workflow create CustomLogs automatically without letting the user create them manually?

Comment: are you setting the owner of customlog as user in WF step?

Comment: @ArunVinoth You were right - I set the wrong test account as owner of the record. Once I switched it to the right account it worked fine. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: glad to help, I'll post it as answer, so you can upvote/accept as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you are setting the user as owner of the created `CustomLog` record in Workflow step. Btw, you can ignore that owner field so that CRM platform can set it for you (the current context user - which is Test account in your case).